Place objects by edge angle
I try create a simple node setup to place objects by spline edge angle. for example if edge is straight (90°) than place cube or if edge is tapered(45°) than place cylinders.
some how i manage but there is some issue in the 45° angle calculation. cylinders are placed on unwanted points.
can someone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks

